PageSpeed Insights returns ERR_TIMED_OUT
i was testing my magento 2 sight in https://pagespeed.web.dev/ in desktop view. it does't give any respose and keep showing following error :
Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)
error image :
https://i.sstatic.net/oo3rONA4.png
https://prnt.sc/7lS4jfh27tPD
what might be the reason for server timeout?

There can be several issues which can block google to access your website and hence, you will get timeout. Some of the reasons can be;

Google robots are blocked in your site's robots.txt.
pagespeed.web.dev or related domains maybe blocked by your hosting.
Your website is too slow to load (greater than 30s) because of which lighthouse is getting timed out.

All of the above process will take a long time to debug, but you can also analyse pagespeed using chrome's inbuilt Lighthouse tool which essentially does the same thing but locally on the browser itself.
